# Error while Replicating an ore.tblmatrix in R?

Tags: r, oracle

Actually, I'm trying to implement **Multivaritate Gaussian distribution** on a dataset from a data center. The data table `NETWORK_DATA_TRAINING` is stored in the **Oracle database**. But, when I tried to replicated the Matrix with columnwise means, it threw an error:

```
library(ORE)
library(pracma)
if (!ore.is.connected())
ore.connect("NETWORK_TBL01", "orcl","192.168.50.19", "test",port=1521, all=TRUE)

X <- NETWORK_DATA_TRAINING[,]
Mu <- colMeans(X)       # class(X) : "ore.frame" , dim(X): 1000 11  
Mu <- as.matrix(Mu)     #class(Mu) : "ore.tblmatrix", dim(Mu):1 11
k <- ncol(Mu)
mu <- matrix(Mu,ncol(X),nrow(X))
```

> error: no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

```
X <- bsxfun("-", X, mu)
print(X)
```

For more, here goes the [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/q9XeTjKuXuTGW8ALZ83sN9).

Comment: I've never used ORE before, but based on my 2 minutes of looking at the documentation, my impression is that the entire package is designed to allow you to operate on objects in the db using R functions _without pulling them into memory_. So everything you're doing with those objects probably is happening in the db. You may have to use `ore.pull` on `Mu`. But again, all I did was skim the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I had to use conversion to table before coercing into matrix.